# How to lay out an HTML page in top, bottom, & right parts? (Concept, not rote)

Tags: iframe, html, page-layout

I want to lay out an HTML page in three parts. One I'll call TOP occupies the upper left part of the window. Another (BOTTOM) occupies the lower left part. The third (RIGHT) occupies the right part.

TOP and BOTTOM have the same width, which is fixed. RIGHT fills the remaining width of the window.

BOTTOM expands vertically to fit its content. TOP fills the remaining height of the window and has a minimum height. RIGHT fills the height of the window.

TOP and RIGHT scroll vertically if their content overflows. BOTTOM hides its overflow (a pathological case that will happen only if the window is made absurdly short).

I want to figure out how to do this myself, but I need some general advice on how to approach it.

Should I do the whole thing with three <iframe>s? With three <div>s using absolute positioning, each containing an <iframe>? With left and right <div>s, top and bottom <div>s in the left <div>, and an <iframe> in each?

What CSS properties should I use to make the <iframe>s or <div>s or whatever behave the way I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with Divs and CSS, just spend some time looking and there is plenty of information out there. I would suggest looking up some basic WebProgramming courses on youtube, really any should do

Answer (score 0):

Use divs, not iframes. Stick this in the body of your web page for a start....

```
<div style="background: red; width: 100%; position: relative; height: 100px">text top
</div>
<div style="background: blue; float: right; width: 50%; max-height: 450px; height: 450px; position: relative; overflow-y: auto"> text right
</div>
<div style="background: gray; width: 100%; position: fixed; bottom: 100px;"> text bottom
</div>
```

Here's a couple of links...
http://css-tricks.com/search-results/?q=div

http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

**Please mark as an answer if you think it helps.**

Comment: Why did I bother... he probably found a snipet on w3schools.com

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments. I'd welcome some specific suggestions for tutorials in this area. (I want _print_ tutorials, not YouTube. That's just how my mind works.) I found nothing that was very clear before posting my question, and I've found nothing new since.

Comment: try clicking the little up arrow if this answer helps